# Sorted features in a QGIS GeoPDF

Tags: qgis, geopdf

I have created a GeoPDF in QGIS and this contains a layer with municipality names. In the PDF Viewer, I would like to view the individual features of the layer, but they are not sorted alphabetically. Is there a way to change this?
The layer contains an FID column, which was automatically generated when the layer was created and which was not sorted alphabetically.

I have therefore created a new column that contains a new ID. Based on the alphabetically sorted column with the municipality names. So the alphabetically first municipality gets the number 1 and so on.

Even with this, the features are not sorted in the PDF. Are there any other options?
[image]